# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' of 'function result'

Tags: flutter, dart

Declared this :

```
List<String> _questionText = new List(creatingQuiz.totalQuestionsCount);
```

Executed this :

```
TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Cannot be empty';
              } else {
                _questionText[qCount] = value;
                return null;
              }
            },
            decoration:
                InputDecoration(labelText: "Question number $count"),
          ),
```

The list type is string, and value is type string too. 
still getting this type error :

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' of 'function result'
```

This is the Stack Trace

```
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _questionText (package:myshipapp/QuizApp/addQuestions.dart)
#1      _MyHomePageState.question.<anonymous closure> 
        package:myshipapp/QuizApp/addQuestions.dart:94
#2      FormFieldState._validate 
        package:flutter/…/widgets/form.dart:392
#3      FormFieldState.validate.<anonymous closure> 
        package:flutter/…/widgets/form.dart:385
#4      State.setState 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1233
```

Comment: post first 5-8 frames from the stacktrace

Comment: @pskink is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, it's a stacktrace

Comment: _questionText[qCount] = value;

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> _questionText = new List<String>(creatingQuiz.totalQuestionsCount);
```

My declaration was incorrect. Thank you everybody.